# mod_evasive not working in Apache 2.4.48 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apache2.4, mod-evasive

I installed mod_evasive as per instructions in https://www.atlantic.net/vps-hosting/how-to-install-and-configure-modevasive-with-apache-on-ubuntu-18-04/ but with configuration like below:

```
    DOSHashTableSize    3097
    DOSPageCount        1
    DOSSiteCount        10
    DOSPageInterval     1
    DOSSiteInterval     1
    DOSBlockingPeriod   10
```

But when I run the perl script I don't see the IP being blacklisted with all requests getting response 200 ok, when I am expecting 403 Forbidden :(

What am I getting wrong??

Additional details: When I re-start my Apache, I  see 6 instances of it. And when I run the test perl script, check for the number of apache instances immediately I see the count at 30-ish instances before it comes down to 10 after a while.

My Apache config looks like below:

```
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
```

My mpm_prefork_module config looks like below:

```
StartServers             5
MinSpareServers          5
MaxSpareServers          10
MaxRequestWorkers        80
MaxConnectionsPerChild   1
```

Is this an issue with Apache configuration??

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not with `mod_evasive` or its configuration per se.

In my case I had to tweak the configuration of `mpm_prefork_module` like below to get mod_evasive configuration to work:

```
StartServers             10
MinSpareServers          10
MaxSpareServers          10
MaxRequestWorkers        80
MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
```

Basically fix the number of servers to constant by setting `StartServers = MinSpareServers = MaxSpareServers = {your_magic_number}` and set `MaxConnectionsPerChild=0`, so that no new server processes are spawned and no re-cycling of connections happen, allowing Child to hold infinitely many concurrent connections.

I lost a day in fixing this one and hope with this answer having the formulae, you don't lose your day :)